# What's the terminology for when a boolean/tagged union determines whether the current execution of a recursive function is at its first iteration?

Tags: haskell, recursion, erlang

I remember seeing in Erlang, that a wrapper function of a recursive function will sometimes pass an atom that determines whether the recursion is at the first iteration (n = 1) or some successive iterations (n > 1). This is useful when a recursive function needs to change its behaviour after the first iteration. What is this pattern called?

Furthermore is this pattern also appropriate in Haskell? I wrote a small snippet using it, **look at the `first` boolean:**

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt, isDigit)

data Token = Num Integer deriving (Show)

tokeniseNumber :: String -> (String, Maybe Token)
tokeniseNumber input = accumulateNumber input 0 True
    where
    accumulateNumber ::  String -> Integer -> Bool -> (String, Maybe Token)
    accumulateNumber [] value True  = ([], Nothing)
    accumulateNumber [] value False = ([], Just (Num value))
    accumulateNumber input@(peek:tail) value first =
        case isDigit peek of
            False | first     -> (input, Nothing)
            False | not first -> (input, Just (Num value))
            True              -> accumulateNumber tail (value * 10 + (toInteger . digitToInt) peek) False
```

-- Edit --

zxq9 posted an answer and later deleted. But I actually think the answer has merit.

> This is cleaner to define as a set of separate functions that each behave some specific way, and a function head match that determines which of those functions to dispatch (Haskell provides a broader array of type-based function matching tools here). In other words, a certain style of "finite state machine" is what you are looking for.
>
> The states can be styled as function names or as a state argument; which to use depends on the context and language, and this can extend to the state argument being a function name and that itself being a sort of match.
>
> What is best for Haskell is usually not what works best for Erlang. Many one-off tasks are delegated to separate processes in Erlang, and even process instantiation in Erlang goes through an "init state" when it calls init, which is essentially the same thing as when you say "when a recursive function needs to change its behaviour after the first iteration". OTOH, Haskell provides more ways to match on a function head. In either case taking an approach where a named function defines an operating state is cleaner. The result will be code that is not nested, doesn't require procedural conditionals, and can be called from anywhere more easily (more flexibly dealt with when you re-write your program later...).
>
> FSMs are a general way of determining what code to execute based on state, and initialization of a function (or process) is a special case of that. I've heard this called "pass-through initialization" as in, the entry function defines the interface, does one-time processing to set up the main procedure and passes execution through to it:
>
> ```
> init(Args) ->
>       {ok, NewArgs} = one_time_processing(Args),
>       loop(NewArgs).
>
> loop(Args) ->
>       {ok, NewArgs} = do_stuff(Args),
>       loop(NewArgs).
> ```
>
> Of course, the above is an infinite loop, so its more common to either have a check for exit at the end of the loop/1 function, or (more often) a match in the function head of loop:
>
> ```
> loop(done, Args) ->
>       Args;
> loop(cont, Args) ->
>       {Cond, NewArgs} = do_stuff(Args),
>       loop(Cond, NewArgs).
> ```
>
> But in either case it is better to have the initialization of a process be its own procedure, separately defined from whatever the body of the loop is. Other languages with looping constructs handle this differently with some combination of conditional checks applied a special way based on which style of loop the programmer chooses, but the effect is the same. Very often the most obvious way to implement this procedurally is to do the same: wrap the whole loop behind a function call, and the steps that precede the loop are the "one time" initialization parts. In this case its not that the loop is "wrapped" in a function call, but that you write an interface function to access it which does some one-time initialization on the way to calling it.

Comment: Beware of [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/); I'd think in most specific cases, you can use something much better than a single boolean (but it will vary from use case to use case).

Comment: Yea, I could use a tagged union, with constructors like `First` `Successive`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment about [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/), I don't just mean using another type isomorphic to `2`, but rather, using the right type to encode the *reason* your recursive function cares about which iteration it is.

Compare your code to the following version which is I'd say cleaner and more succint. It hinges on passing a `Maybe Integer` instead of an `(Integer, Bool)` to `accumulateNumber`.

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt, isDigit)
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

data Token = Num Integer deriving (Show)

tokeniseNumber :: String -> (String, Maybe Token)
tokeniseNumber input = accumulateNumber input Nothing
  where
    accumulateNumber ::  String -> Maybe Integer -> (String, Maybe Token)
    accumulateNumber input@(peek:tail) value
      | isDigit peek = accumulateNumber tail (Just $ toNum (fromMaybe 0 value) peek)
    accumulateNumber input value = (input, Num <$> value)

    toNum value peek = value * 10 + (toInteger . digitToInt) peek
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was thinking of trying something similar, but your one does make use of more abstractions. Do you know what this pattern is called?

Comment: Actually there's another nice case of boolean blindness in that code, in the interaction of `isDigit` and  `digitToInt` :) A nicer version would be something of type `Char -> Maybe Int` that combines the two.

Comment: What I meant was simply that I'm not sure there's a generalizable pattern here beyond the fold itself (`accumulateNumber` is a left fold over `input`).

Comment: I'm not sure about fold, because the function terminates without running over the entire input. It's meant to stop once it meets anything that's not a digit. Can there be an implementation that folds but lazily stops on some condition? (So it's not traversing the entire list)

Answer (score 0):

Also wanted to point out that I discovered an academic paper that discusses this exact technique.

It's called the "The worker/wrapper transformation" by Andy Gill & Graham Hutton (2009)

Link: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/wrapper.pdf